# No such file or directory

Tags: python, split, path, pattern-matching, shutil

[image]I have faced error I had worked with this code before but now:

error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pattern2_list.txt'
```

I use Python 3.8

```py
import os
import shutil

with open ("pattern2_list.txt") as pattern_list_file: 

    pattern_data = pattern_list_file.read ()
    pattern_list = pattern_data.split('\n')[:-1]

file_name_list = [file_name for file_name in os.listdir('2020')]

for file_name in file_name_list:
    for pattern in pattern_list:
        if pattern in file_name:
            shutil.move("2020/" + file_name, "new_dir/"+ file_name)
```

Comment: Well, is this file still present?

Comment: Are you in the correct directory?

Comment: Hi I attached image that shows  derive " D:\hello" and my files

Comment: run the script from the D drive

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the file `pattern2_list.txt`
is present in the same working directory.
If you are in same directory and still it is not working then open a new folder and inside it create your python file with`.py`extension.Inside same folder paste the `pattern2_list.txt`file and then try to use it.
If still facing issue then check your python path in environment variable and if possible restart your system then open vs code.

Hope it will help you..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).